# Change the path of website to another drive in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I wanted to know the steps for changing the path of website in iis.

I have a website configured on C: but due to disk space issues i want to move it to another drive.
Can this be done without changing the path of inetpub and just changing the path of website?
Also does it affect ftp settings?

Comment: Is the Web site hosted on IIS virtual directory?

Comment: YEs Website is hosted on iis virtual directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just change the Physical path of the sie using inetmgr tool. It doesnt have to be inside inetpub.

But be careful to set appropriate permissions for NETWORK_SERVICE or any other user running your web application.